# Дописать текст в файл

Tags: c#, файлы

Здраствуйте, я б хотел узнать, возможно ли записать данные в файл .txt формата в определенной позиции, что-то на примере бинарных файлов, где есть функция seek, которая, устанавливает указатель файла на какую-то позицию?

Comment: Вставить данные в середину - нельзя (так же как и в бинарном файле). Перезаписать данные, затерев старые - в принципе можно. Всё зависит от кодировки.

Answer (score 3):

Текстовые файлы не предназначены для дописывания в середину. При попытке сделать это возникает множество проблем.

1. Юникодные текстовые кодировки (utf-8 и utf-16), а также другие (например, ISO-2022) обладают переменным размером. Это значит, что для того, чтобы найти позицию символа по его номеру, вам придётся читать весь текст с самого начала файла: вы не можете по номеру символа установить номер байта.
2. Даже если ваша кодировка случайно имеет фиксированную ширину, обычно запись необходимо производить не по номеру символа, а по номеру *строки*. Тут возникает дополнительная сложность в том, что строки имею разную длину, а также в том, что символы концов строк в текстовом файле могут быть разными: это символы с кодами `0x0A`, `0x0D`, их сочетание `0x0A 0x0D`, а также менее известные `0x85`, `0x2028` и `0x2029`.
3. Запись символов в файл с кодировкой переменного размера поверх других невозможна: если вы записываете однобайтный символ поверх 3-байтного, вы превращаете текст в невалидный. Точно так же, даже для кодировок фиксированного размера запись поверх других символов может уничтожить символы перевода строки.

Поэтому самым простым методом работы с текстовыми файлами является создание нового файла с нужным вам преобразованным текстом, и последующая замена старого на новый.